# Axiomatizing stacks and queues using first-order logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

In the textbook I'm using to prepare the logic exam says that first order logic may be used to <strike>implement</strike> axiomatize data structures. There is an example of that:

"Stack": uses a language that contains the <strike>predicates</strike> functions *top*, *pop* and *push*, and the constant *nil* (empty stack). It axioms are:

- $\forall s \forall x . top(push(s, x))=x$
- $\forall s \forall x . pop(push(s, x))=s$
- $\forall s . push(pop(s), top(s))=s$

Premise: that I didn't understand this example completely (there's no explanation about how can these axioms describe a stack).

Suppose I have to describe another data structure, for example a "Queue", what strategy do you follow to write the axioms of this data structure? Can you make an example of the axioms you would use?

**EDIT**:
Using the @user21820 's answer as an example, I'm trying to answer my own question.

Strategy:

1. Describe the language used: $(Queue, add, remove, element, nil)$ where

   - $Queue$ is an unary predicate, $Queue(x)$ means $x \in Queue$;
   - $add$ is a binary function. $add(q, e), q \in Queue$ returns the queue with a new element at the end of the queue;
   - $remove$ is a binary function. $remove(q, e), q \in Queue$ returns the queue without the first element of the queue;
   - $element$ is a unary function that returns the first element of the queue.
   - $nil$ is a constant, means empty queue.
2. Describe the axioms you need (they might be wrong):

   - remove an element from a queue with one element return the empty queue;
   - remove an element from a queue return the queue without the first element;
   - add an element from the queue returns the queue with the element added;
   - element function returns the first element inserted;
3. Write the axioms:

   - $remove(add(nil, x)) = nil$
   - $\forall q \in Queue. \left(remove(add(q, x)) = ???\right)$
   - $???$
   - $???$

Comment: I choose "Queue" because the first exercise of the chapter says: describe queue and tree data structures with a first order language with identity

Comment: From the book "Logica ad informatica", Asperti, Ciabattoni; chapter 4

Comment: I've edited your question to make it easier to find and to fix the errors in the statement of the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer that applies if you do not allow the length function for stacks/queues.

### Stacks

If you take away the axioms about the length of stacks, there are worlds that satisfy the axioms but have very weird behaviour. (I was writing a more detailed version of this section but lost the whole lot accidentally. I'm not going to rewrite it, sorry.)

In one world, $push([0,0],0) = nil$, and $pop(nil) = [0,0]$ and $top(nil) = 0$, and everything else is as usual. In another, every stack consists of finitely many items on top of $nil$, while $nil$ is actually an infinite stack of turtles all the way down, and of course $push(nil,) = pop(nil) = nil$. In a third, there are both finite stacks including $nil$ and infinite stacks that are eventually turtles all the way down, and the infinite turtle stack is not $nil$. If one varies the nature of the infinite stacks one can get interesting behaviour; it could be that every infinite stack is eventually an alternating stack $T$ of  and   at the bottom, such that $push(push(T,),) = T$ but still we have $push(s,x) \ne s$ for every stack $s$ and object $x$.

The best you can do if you do not have the length function is to add the following axioms:

> $\forall s \in Stacks\ \forall x\ ( push(s,x) \ne nil )$.
>
> $\forall s \in Stacks\ \forall x\ ( push(s,x) \ne s )$.
>
> $\forall s \in Stacks\ \forall x,y\ ( push(push(s,x),y) \ne s )$.
>
> ... [generalize to all possible number of pushes] ...

At least this axiomatization allows you to prove or disprove every true sentence you can state over the original language. (If I'm not mistaken.)

It also prevents the weird worlds mentioned above, though there are other non-standard worlds that satisfy even this. One of them is as follows. Every stack is either a standard finite stack or a bi-directional infinite array with an index $p$ that is filled up to cell $p$ and is empty from cell $p+1$ onwards. Operations on the standard stacks are as usual. Operations on the non-standard stacks is done as if the filled cells form a stack with cell $p$ at the top, so pushing an item will fill cell $p+1$, while popping will erase cell $p$, and $p$ is incremented or decremented as appropriate. You can check that all the axioms are satisfied.

### Queues

As with stacks, what you can axiomatize for queues is limited if you do not have a length function, but let's see what can be done.

First let's look at your attempt:

- remove(add(nil,x))=nil

  Invalid because you didn't specify $x$. The correct version is:

  > $\forall x\ ( remove(add(nil,x)) = nil )$.
- ∀q∈Queue.(remove(add(q,x))=???)

  You probably realize that you can't determine what's left behind.

  Well for a non-empty queue the order of adding an item or removing the first does not matter.
- ???

  In first-order logic you cannot specify the output type of a function.

  Read and follow my example for stacks properly.

  You're also missing axioms specifying the first element of a queue.

[Try before looking below.]

> $\forall q \in Queues\ \forall x\ ( add(q,x) \in Queues )$.
>
> $\forall q \in Queues\ ( q \ne nil \to pop(q) \in Queues )$.
>
> $nil \in Queues$.
>
> $\forall x\ ( first(add(nil,x)) = x )$.
>
> $\forall q \in Queues\ \forall x\ ( q \ne nil \to first(add(q,x)) = first(q) )$.
>
> $\forall x\ ( remove(add(nil,x)) = nil )$.   [The one you thought of.]
>
> $\forall q \in Queues\ \forall x\ ( q \ne nil \to remove(add(q,x)) = add(remove(q),x) )$.
>
> $\forall q \in Queues\ \forall x\ ( add(q,x) \ne nil )$.
>
> $\forall q \in Queues\ \forall x\ ( add(q,x) \ne q )$.
>
> $\forall q \in Queues\ \forall x,y\ ( add(add(q,x),y) \ne q )$.
>
> ... [generalize to all possible number of adds] ...
>
> $\forall q \in Queues\ ( q \ne nil \to remove(q) \ne q )$.
>
> $\forall q \in Queues\ ( q \ne nil \land remove(q) \ne nil \to remove(remove(q)) \ne q )$.
>
> ... [generalize to all possible number of removes] ...

I think these axioms will allow you to prove any true sentence about queues in the given language. But they will not prevent a world with non-standard queues. Similar to the non-standard world at the end of the section about stacks, one can have a world where a non-standard queue is a queue with an infinite front and infinite back, each stored in an infinite array where the position of both the first and last items are tracked.

Comment: Wonderful, really. Just one another question (hoping it's allowed to ask such things on stackexchange): can you suggest me any book that explains these things (=specify the behavior of a data structure, how to axiomatize it) to understand deeper this topic?

Comment: @Ignus: I'm sorry I can't help with that because I didn't learn this from anywhere. But it is certainly allowed to ask such things. (If you do ask a new question about it, just tag it "reference-request".) I highly doubt that there's any good textbook for this because there is no systematic way at all. However, I do recommend that you pick up some logic, as knowing logic well will greatly assist you in figuring out which axioms you need. For that I suggested some books in one of my posts linked from my profile.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, $push,pop,top$ are not predicates but functions, otherwise your axioms are syntactically meaningless in first-order logic.

The axioms describe some guarantees of the stack **interface**:

1. The top of a stack is the last item pushed onto it.
2. Popping a stack after pushing an item onto it gives you the original stack.
3. Popping a stack and then pushing the original top item gives you the original stack.

It is actually not the case that these axioms are enough, nor are they actually correct. There are glaring issues:

- The quantifiers are not restricted, so the axiom governs $push(s,x)$ even when $s$ is not a stack. This is not technically a problem (garbage in, garbage out) but is a severe violation of type-safety.
- Worse still, what happens if the stack is empty? For the axioms to hold, you would need 'negative-height' stacks to exist. For instance $nil$ must have a top element and there must be a stack such that when you push $top(nil)$ onto it you get $nil$!
- Also, it's not possible to state or prove certain properties about stacks without adding more axioms. For example you can't state anything about the length of stacks.

A proper axiomatization of stacks would look something like:
$\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}$

> [Add function symbol $len$ to the language.]
>
> [Add predicates $Stacks,\nn$ to the language.]
>
> $\forall s \in Stacks\ \forall x\ ( push(s,x) \in Stacks )$.
>
> $\forall s \in Stacks\ \forall x\ ( s \ne nil \to pop(s) \in Stacks )$.
>
> $nil \in Stacks$.
>
> $\forall s \in Stacks\ \forall x\ ( top(push(s,x)) = x )$.
>
> $\forall s \in Stacks\ \forall x\ ( pop(push(s,x)) = s )$.
>
> $\forall s \in Stacks\ ( s \ne nil \to push(pop(s),top(s)) = s )$.
>
> $\forall s \in Stacks\ ( len(s) \in \nn )$.
>
> $\forall s \in Stacks\ \forall x\ ( len(push(s,x)) = len(s)+1 )$.
>
> $\forall s \in Stacks\ ( s \ne nil \to len(s) = len(pop(s))+1 )$.
>
> $\forall s \in Stacks\ ( s = nil \to len(s) = 0 )$.
>
> [Add all the standard axioms about the natural numbers $\nn$.]

Note that "$x \in P$" here can be understood to mean "$P(x)$", and likewise a restricted quantification "$\forall x \in P\ ( \cdots )$" can be taken as "$\forall x\ ( P(x) \to \cdots )$".

Comment: Excellent answer. Just another question: there is a strategy/algorithm/procedure to choose the axioms? And how can I write them correctly?
I added to my question, following your example, a sort of answer to the queue problem. Would you give a look at that?

Comment: @Ignus: Well before one can ask for an algorithm one has to precisely specify the input. It is circular in this case, because you need a formal system to specify the desired behaviour, and if your formal system is a first-order system then you're already done once you can even specify your question! If your formal specification is not first-order, however, I think there's no algorithm to generate an equivalent first-order axiom system even if the input is guaranteed to have one.

Comment: @Ignus: In short, writing down axioms for some intuitive concept is clearly a matter of intuition and design. As for your queue question, you didn't specify what behaviour you want, so how can we axiomatize it? To clarify, the problem is precisely in the lack of specification. You say "the queue with the element added", but that's meaningless to anyone who does not know what a queue is. If you unambiguously describe what you mean by that, you'll realize that you probably need a formal system powerful enough to talk about strings (finite sequences).

Comment: @Ignus: I've given you another answer that does not involve natural numbers and lengths. Naturally, you need quite a number of axioms to express (most of) the desired behaviour. The advantage of bring in natural numbers is that you can axiomatize multiple data structures together, and if you extend the language sufficiently you would be able to prove statements involving different data structures. You can't do this if you cannot even say something like "a stack and queue of the same length". Also, if you find my answers helpful, you can upvote and/or accept. =)